# How to make a ui element without using a blender property

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a float field or a int field slider like

```
layout.prop(a, "my_prop")
```

I want that but without using the prop field is this possible?
[image: blender image]

This is a example of what I mean.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what it would look like (code-wise)  and how it would be used?

Comment: The gui field depends on the property type (StringProperty, FloatProperty, EnumProperty).. but I added a image for you any of them...

Comment: Still unclear to me what you are asking. The UI source of your example can be investigated by right clicking and choosing "Edit Source".  [`UILayout.prop`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=uilayout#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) has a number of options including for ints and floats  `slider=True` and `text=""` to markup a slider like render %age above.

Comment: Im not asking that I want to create a gui field like the float fields and enum fields WITHOUT bpy.props?? Does that make it more clear?

Comment: You can use any Blender data to get a GUI field.  For example: `layout.prop(bpy.context.active_object, 'location')`